# escape error strings in blade laravel

Tags: laravel-5

blade:

```
    @if ($errors->has('email'))
 <span class="help-block"> <strong>
{!! html_entity_decode( $errors->first('email') )!!}</strong> </span> 
@endif
```

controller:

```
if($user == null){
                return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => "This e-mail is not exist in our database. Please <a href='/register'>register</a>"]);
            }
```

I expect to see clickable 'register' link in ui but its raw string as you see:
[image]

I tried also '@' and '{{{ }}}' symbols, none of them work..

Comment: I see no issues. Your code showing a link when I tested

Comment: @RubabHossain yeah and I am afraid of that of course.. what suppose to be wrong here still cant figure out